# WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 - Cannot remove "Server" header

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

According to official [docs](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/removing-specific-request-headers-from-response/#removing-specific-request-headers-from-response) defining a custom out sequence and adding `<property name="CustomTransportHeader" scope="transport" action="remove"/>` would remove any unwanted header from api response, yet I'm not getting any success defining a custom global out sequence and trying to remove **Server** out of response headers nor any other headers as well.

```
 * Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
 < HTTP/1.1 200 
 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
 < Date: Tue, 18 May 2021 14:37:47 GMT
 < Content-Type: application/json
 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 < Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
```

Here's the custom out sequence which I placed in`{$APIM_HOME}/repository/deployment/server/synapse_configs/sequences` folder as a new xml file and got acknowledged of it's deployment by log:

```
 <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="WSO2AM--Ext--Out"> 
  <property name="Server" scope="transport" action="remove"/>
 <log level="custom">
   <property name="TRACE" value="API Mediation Extension"/>
 </log>
 </sequence>
```

how should one get this done? what's the problem here?

Comment: Did you associate the sequence with the API? https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/deploy-and-publish/deploy-on-gateway/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/

Comment: @VithursaM want it to be effective on all APIs within the api manager not only the APIs that i made, for instance I want to change the response headers on `/apis` api which retrieves the APIs list, what should I do in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody struggling with this, all you have to do is to add this Entry into your `deployment.toml` file:

```
[transport.https.properties]
server = "something"
```

this would change the `Server` in response headers to your desired value. using custom sequences can do no good as you don't want to modify your own defined APIs and your request is not passing through it at all.