# WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 - Response Header update

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager, apim

I am studying Open source API manager implementation on microservices and I start with WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0 using the available [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn) but many solutions mentioned in the document doesn't work.

For example, I checked a forum where people are trying to remove some parts of Response headers especially ***server: WSO2 Carbon Server***. As per documentation it says update *<API-M_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/sequences/main.xml* and add lines mentioned here https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/removing-specific-request-headers-from-response/#removing-specific-request-headers-from-response. This did not work for me.

[image]

Is this something only available in licensed version or what is the correct process?

Comment: Can you share which API you are trying to invoke and observe this behaviour? Is it any API configured and published via the Publisher portal, or any API Manager's in-house APIs (such as Token generation etc.)? Furthermore, can you also add the changes that you have made to the `main.xml` in the question? Also share whether you are running the API Manager in a single pack or in a distributed setup.

Comment: Maybe this answer will be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588513/wso2-api-manager-3-2-0-cannot-remove-server-header